# Celery task logging ERROR instead of INFO

Tags: django, celery

I have a number of expected exceptions which should mark the task failed, but log them at INFO level instead of ERROR.

According to the celery [documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#Task.throws):

```
@shared_task(throws=(KeyError, HttpNotFound)): 
def get_foo():
    something()
```

Should log KeyError at INFO level. And it does.

**But if I do:**

```
@periodic_task
def run_get_foo():
    get_foo.delay()
```

KeyError is logged as an actual error

Comment: got anything on this?